# Password change consistently fails with error

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, password

My current password on Stack Exchange is old enough that it needs an update. I used Firefox to log into the gardening Stack Exchange with my email and password, clicked my user and on "Edit Profile & Settings", and on "My Logins". I was shown that I have logins for Stack Exchange and for Facebook. For Stack Exchange I clicked on "change password". I was invited to enter my current password and two copies of my new password. For the new password I picked "newpassword7". Before I typed the "7" there was a message saying:

> Please add one of the following things to make your password stronger:
>
> - numbers

When I typed the "7" the message changed to:

> Password cannot be empty.

The password confirmation field gave the same complaint that the password cannot be empty when I had finished typing it. I think the reason the error shows is that it was hidden behind the larger first message and never cleared.

When I finished filling the fields and clicked "Change Password" a message popped up that said:

> An error occurred while attempting to reset password:

Note that this is the complete error message, blank after the colon.

I tried the same procedure with Chrome and Internet Explorer with the same results. Can someone help me understand the cause of the final error and how to get my password changed?

Comment: Please do not use "newpassword7" or any password similar to that once this error is fixed, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Disable any userscript that might mess with the HTML/JS involved in the process, which can be any userscript or browser plugin (e.g. even some innocent script meant to hide ads or HNQ). Those are often causing unexpected problems exactly like this one. If this problem would have been on SE side, we'd surely have seen more reports.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I did not plan to use "newpassword7" in the first place and only used it here as an example which reproduces the error. I have not modified any of the three freshly-installed browsers that I mentioned. So I think that this error which is not being reported by others may be due to my account history. For example, I had an account at askubuntu.com that seemed to become a Stack Exchange site at some point, with the same login.

Comment: I just changed my password without any error, i.e. it's not persistent for everyone.

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here on Firefox 62.0.3 on 2018-10-08 and 2018-10-09 when I attempt to update my password to a stronger one.  Temporarily disabling Javascript does not help.

Edit Profile & Settings > My Logins > change password gives the same error messages as mentioned in the original post and then ends in "Too many failed current password attempts; please try again later or visit account recovery."  I have now had the same problem for 2 days in a row.

Obviously something is broken.